# make my project maximize by default

Tags: fullscreen, flash-cs5, maximize

im not too well versed in flash, i have a c#, java, c++ background so coding comes a little naturally

as of right now i have three soundslides projects playing in my flash project. The project has three buttons which load each different soundslide.

when classmates and my professor open my program the default size it too small, right now when i click ctrl+enter the bottom and bottom right portion of the screen are cut off...so i have to maximize the window maximize so i can see the play buttons?

Answer (score 0):

stage["displayState"]="fullScreen";

This will make the SWF go fullscreen, if you put this in your document class constructor it will happen as the swf loads.